# jQuery form.submit() not always called

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I use the following javascript code to do some checks before a form is submitted:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    var is_error = false;

   // do certain checks and if some of them fail set is_error = true

   if(!is_error)
        return;

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This works perfectly and everything is fine actually.

However, I found out that this function is not necessarily always called on a form submit. (I was not able to reproduce this behavior by myself but I saw that on my error logs).

This is what I did to get this information:

I added an hidden input field to the form:

```
<input id="input-is_used_function" type="hidden" name="is_used_function" value="0" />
```

And i also adjusted the javascript the following way:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    var is_error = false;

   // do certain checks and if some of them fail set is_error = true

   $('#input-is_used_function').val(1);

   if(!is_error)
        return;

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

After the submit I logged all transmitted POST vars and I found out that 'is_used_function' is sometimes 0, which means that the jQuery submit function has never been called.

Does somebody has a solution for this or at least a hint on how this behavior happens?

Best,

Freddy

Comment: Your conclusion does not follow as there is intervening code. Also, how can there be an error log from an event that does not occur?

Comment: I logged all transmitted POST variables on all form submits and 'is_used_function' is 0 in some cases, which actually cannot happen, since the submit function should have been called on all form submits.

Comment: Why are you testing this way anyway? If you want to see if a function is called, add the logging as first line of function. It sounds like you have a lot more code involved but it is not shown nor is the form itself.

Comment: Well sounds like maybe an error happened in your code before it was set and the regular form submitted? Hard to tell with what is provided.

Comment: Javascript logging does not do any good, since i cannot reproduce the error myself.

So, you mean that there happens an error in the javascript during execution of the submit function and this causes the form to submit?